# MasterPage with slight modification. Do I need to create a new one?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Working on a ASP.NET webform project.  I have a MasterPage which works fine for 99% of my pages.  However, on one page where I use a GridView, I need a slighty altered version of this MasterPage.  I basically need to remove a few lines off of it:

```
    <%--<div id="pageContentInner">--%>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    <%--</div>--%>
```

Do I need to create a completely separate MasterPage or is there a way to disable that part only for that one page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating another `MasterPage` is probably the right way to go. Although you could do something like this:

Change your `MasterPage` div that needs to be invisible to a `Panel`.

Add a Property in the `MasterPage` to toggle visibility of that Panel:

```
public bool PageContentInnerViewable
{
    get
    {
        return PageContentInner.Visible;
    }
    set
    {
        PageContentInner.Visible = value;
    }
}
```

Change the visibility in page code-behind

```
this.Master.PageContentViewable = false;
```